# WHY MY nn.Identity() function is changing shape?

Tags: pytorch, model, vision

[TORCH INFO SUMMARY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euzxm.png)The given code snippet pertains to a PyTorch model named "model1" and involves the application of the Identity() transformation to various components of the model. This transformation is essentially a no-op operation, meaning it leaves the input unchanged. Let's break down the code and understand its implications.

1. model1.encoder.ln=Identity(): Here, an instance of the Identity() transformation is assigned to the 'ln' attribute of the 'encoder' module within 'model1'. The 'encoder' module might refer to a specific part of the model responsible for encoding or feature extraction. By applying Identity() to 'ln', any input passed through 'encoder.ln' will remain unaltered. This could be useful in scenarios where you want to inspect the raw output of the encoder.
2. model1.head=Identity(): In this line, the 'head' attribute of 'model1' is assigned an instance of Identity(). 'head' is likely a module that performs some sort of post-processing on the encoded features. The usage of Identity() here suggests that no post-processing is desired, and the raw features from the encoder will be directly used.
3. model1.heads=Identity(): Similarly, 'heads' attribute within 'model1' is assigned Identity(). This might refer to multiple heads of the model, each handling different aspects of the problem. Applying Identity() here implies that the output from these heads remains unchanged.
4. model1.fc=Identity(): The 'fc' attribute in 'model1' stands for fully connected layer. Assigning Identity() to it indicates that the output of this layer, which is usually a linear transformation followed by an activation, will be skipped or bypassed. This could be used to examine the intermediate output or debug the model's behavior.